# using TinyXML Parsing XML Elements

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, tinyxml

This should be a pretty easy question for people who have used TinyXML. I'm attempting to use TinyXML to parse through an XML document and pull out some values. I figured out how to add in the library yesterday, and I have successfully loaded the document (hey, it's a start).

I've been reading through the manual and I can't quite figure out how to pull out individual attributes. After Googling around, I haven't found an example of my specific example, so perhaps someone here who has used TinyXML can help out. Below is a slice of the XML, and where I have started to parse it.

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hnisi>
<head><version>1.0</version></head>
<body>
    <params>
      <param key="FHZ" val="1" />
      <param key="MSG" val="login failed" />
       <param key="SESSIONID" val="HISID6B5FD5E290884C77A2BA827AA2B1E53D" />
    </params>
   </body>
</hnisi>
```

Loading/parsing code:

```
  TiXmlDocument doc;
     const char *filedate=response.return_->c_str();
     doc.Parse(filedata, 0, TIXML_ENCODING_UTF8);

     TiXmlElement *pRoot, *pParm, *pProcess, *pApp, *pLineFormat;
      pRoot = XMLdoc.FirstChildElement( "hnisi" );
      if ( pRoot )
      {
           pParm= pRoot->FirstChildElement( "params" );
           while(pParm)
           {
             // I don't know  here,how do I read the  attribute of value of FHZ,MSG and SESSIONID?


           }
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed to get the `<body>` element, which is a child of `<hnisi>`, and then you want to have the `<param>` elements which are children of `<params>` in your xml. To get the attributes just use the `Attribute` function of [TiXmlElement](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlElement.html).

```
TiXmlDocument doc("yourfile.xml");
if(doc.LoadFile())
{
    TiXmlElement *pRoot, *pBody, *pParms, *pProcess, *pApp, *pLineFormat, *pParm;
    pRoot = doc.FirstChildElement( "hnisi" );
    if ( pRoot )
    {
        pBody= pRoot->FirstChildElement( "body" ); //body should be read
        if (pBody) {
            pParms= pBody->FirstChildElement( "params" ); //now params
            if(pParms)
            {
                pParm=pParms->FirstChildElement("param");
                while (pParm) {
                    // now loop al param elements and get their attributes
                    std::cout <<"key="<<pParm->Attribute("key")<<std::endl;
                    std::cout <<"val="<<pParm->Attribute("val")<<std::endl;

                    //next sibling
                    pParm=pParm->NextSiblingElement("param");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```